# Можно ли в пункте service указать путь до файла env?

Tags: docker-compose

В документации указан пример [для сервиса](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#:%7E:text=for%20more%20information.-,Use%20the%20env_file%20attribute,-You%20can%20pass)

```
web:
  env_file:
    - web-variables.env
```

А можно ли указывать не в описании сервиса, а прям в самом сервисе, например так, чтобы каждому сервису не пихать файл с переменными окружения:

```
version: "3"
services:
  env_file:
    - .env/my_env
  serv1:
    ....
  serv2:
    ....
  serv3:
    ....
```

Comment: Нет. На верхнем уровне [допустимы](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/03-compose-file/) только version, services, networks, volumes, configs, secrets